# Prerequisites for JP Serre’s “A Course in Arithmetic

Tags: number-theory

It seems as though abstract algebra, p-adic numbers, and complex analysis are prerequisites, but I’m curious if there are any others.

Comment: It will define the p-adic numbers for you from scratch, but is a rather terse book so you may prefer to have other references on the side. The general language of abstract algebra is indeed a prerequisite. You don't need much complex analysis in the first half.

Comment: More important than prerequisites is the willingness to understand every line by reading and searching other references if necessary.

Comment: @hunter A slightly unrelated question: Since the book defines p-adic numbers, is it necessary to learn p-adic numbers from another text?(I eventually want to study p-adic geometry.)

Comment: @AdamFrench This book is good for learning what a $p$-adic number is. Of course other references may help too (e.g. the Wikipedia article).